# Specific contour integral around essential singularity

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

Is there a "closed-form" expression for
$$ \oint \mathrm{d}z \, \exp\left( a z^2 + b z + c/z \right) \,, $$
for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\oint$ means contour integral along a path winding once (counterclockwise) around the origin $z = 0$?

Comment: What is the context of the question?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was not quite awake when I wrote the answer, it does not really help that much, so I deleted it. It looks like you are stuck with complicated infinite series expressions.

Comment: No no, thank you for your input. The modified Bessel function of the first kind that arises when $a = 0$ has some infinite series expansion but it is still a well-studied object. When $a \neq 0$ the situation is more difficult it seems, because you have a finite sum (instead of a single term) inside the infinite sum.

Comment: @Latrace You had written that you know that PRODUCT rule $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$ and its generalization (Leibniz's rule for differentiating products).  That is different from the chain (composite) rule $\frac{d f(g(x))}{dx}=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ and its generalization, [Faa Di Bruno's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula), which involves the Bell Polynomials and is considerably more difficult.

Comment: @MarkViola: I see, thanks for the explanation of that formula. Do you think this helps in solving the integral?

Comment: You're welcome.  I suggest that you try applying the FdB formula, set $z=0$ and see if it reduces to a manageable form.